# c# how to print window form without window form borders

Tags: c#

I have a window form. I want to print the contents of the form without the window appearance. I mean I want to print it like a receipt, without window borders. How do I do this?

Comment: Set FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;

Comment: Why not a search on MSDN Documentation? --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle

Answer (score 1):

You can take the MSDN example on how to [Print to a Windows Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6he9hz8c.aspx), Change the Surface being printed from the Form to a Panel Control, which will enable you to print without Borders. Your Contents will have to be added to the Panel instead of the Form but it will work. Here is a modified example of the MSDN example.

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private Panel printPanel = new Panel();
    private Button printButton = new Button();
    private PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();

    public Form1()
    {
        printPanel.Size = this.ClientSize;
        this.Controls.Add(printPanel);
        printButton.Text = "Print Form";
        printButton.Click += new EventHandler(printButton_Click);
        printDocument1.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
        printPanel.Controls.Add(printButton);

    }

    void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CaptureScreen();
        printDocument1.Print();
    }


    Bitmap memoryImage;

    private void CaptureScreen()
    {
        Graphics myGraphics = printPanel.CreateGraphics();
        Size s = printPanel.Size; 
        memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics);
        Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
        Point screenLoc = PointToScreen(printPanel.Location); // Get the location of the Panel in Screen Coordinates
        memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(screenLoc.X, screenLoc.Y, 0, 0, s);
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(System.Object sender,
           System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, 0, 0);
    }



    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can just get a blank screen by doing something like this

```
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormsBorderStyle.None;
this.ControlBox = false;
this.Text = String.Empty;
```