# C# Newbie - Vector Printing of Visio Document using AxVisioViewer ActiveX control

Tags: activex, visio

I am using VS2013Express to create a windows form based application which will display and eventually print Visio documents, rather than relying on the browser based Visio Viewer. Needless to say this is a very specific requirement, so really don't need anyone telling me to use the MS Visio Viewer!

So far, I can open the Visio document, display it using the AxVisioViewer.dll control. I can even print... to a degree.

The issue is that I can only print currently using a PrintFromScreen method which basically captures the image of the form as displayed on screen and creates a Raster BitMap of it.

I copy the BitMap image to a hidden panel on the form (to remove toolbars etc), then print the contents of the panel. Simple (ish)!

Here's a [link to the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966400/c-sharp-how-to-print-window-form-without-window-form-borders) I used to create the panel and print the image.

What I want to be able to do is resize (Vector not Raster to retain scale) and centre the image as required to ensure the document prints properly.

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Please can you edit your post to include your failing code? You'll get more help that way.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to center the drawing in the control.
Check the following link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/visio-vba/articles/viewer-zoomtorect-method-visio-viewer

You may also check the zoom and pan methods.